# Publishing Pages creation during Site creation through site definition

Tags: publishing-page, feature-activation, site-definition, feature-stapling, onet

I have deployed a custom site definition.. Features available in onet.xml are -

**Site Features-**

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Publishing Workflow feature

**Web Features**

Office SharePoint Server Publishing.

I also have 3 modules, that deploys master pages, page layouts and display templates respectively.

Now I have added a feature receiver and on feature activating , I am creating Publishing Pages based on the deployed custom page layout. Code is below.

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\ADLATempSPAdmin\Desktop\Logging.txt", "started");
            SPSite site1 = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWeb web1 = site1.OpenWeb();
            PublishingSite PublishingSite = new PublishingSite(site1);
            PublishingWeb publishingWeb1 = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web1);
            string pageName1 = "MyCustomPage.aspx";
            SPContentType ctype = PublishingSite.ContentTypes["Article Page"];
            PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = PublishingSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\ADLATempSPAdmin\Desktop\Logging.txt", web1.Url);
            PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts[web1.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/SchoolLayout.aspx"];


            //PageLayout[] pageLayouts1 = publishingWeb1.GetAvailablePageLayouts();
            //PageLayout currPageLayout = pageLayouts1[0];
            PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb1.GetPublishingPages();
            PublishingPage newPage1 = pages.Add(pageName1, pageLayout);
            newPage1.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = "This is my content";
            newPage1.ListItem.Update();
            newPage1.Update();
            newPage1.CheckIn("This is just a comment");

}
```

But I am getting error while creating a site collection, based on my custom site definition. "

**The site is not valid. The ‘Pages’ document library is missing.**

I read that, **our feature receivers should not have dependencies on the features written in onet.xml**. Is that right?

If so, my publishing feature is activated after my event is fired. so "Pages" document library is not present.

How should I proceed now. I am scratching my head for days in this. Please help.

Comment: Did you get it working? Did my code helps you anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to Create a Publishing Page Programmatically in SharePoint 2013. You will get the idea from it.

```
protected void btnCreatePage_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             try
             {
                 string currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Title;
                 string strPageURL = txtURL.Text.Trim() + ".aspx";
                 string strPageTitle = txtTitle.Text.Trim();
                 string strCreatedPageURL = string.Empty;
                 string layoutName = GetLayoutName(ddlContentType.SelectedValue); 
                 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                 {
                     using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                     {
                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite oPublishingSite = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite(oSite);

                         SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();
                         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                         Guid PagesID = web.Lists["Pages"].ID;

                         web.AllProperties["__PagesListId"] = PagesID.ToString();
                         //web.Update();
                         //web.AllProperties["__PublishingFeatureActivated"] = "True";
                         //web.Update();

                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb oPublishingWeb = Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayoutCollection layoutCollection = oPublishingSite.GetPageLayouts(false);

                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout layout = layoutCollection[layoutName];

                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage page = oPublishingWeb.GetPublishingPage(web.Url + "/Pages/" + strPageURL);

                         if (page == null)
                         {
                             page = oPublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(strPageURL, layout);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             throw new Exception("A page with the given URL already exists. Please try a different URL");
                         }

                         if (page.ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser == null)
                         {
                             page.CheckOut();
                         }


                         page.Title = strPageTitle;
                         page.Update();
                         page.CheckIn("Page Created");


                         //page.ListItem.File.Publish("Page Published");

                         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                         strCreatedPageURL = web.Url + "/Pages/" + strPageURL;
                     }
                 });

                 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                 sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
                 sb.Append(@"CallBackSuccess('" + strCreatedPageURL + "');");
                 sb.Append(@"</script>");
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JCall1", sb.ToString(), false);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                 sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
                 sb.Append(@"CallBackFailure('" + ex.Message + "');");
                 sb.Append(@"</script>");
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JCall1", sb.ToString(), false);
                 Logger.LogException("Error has occured on CreatePage Functionality and error message :: " + ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "CreatePage", "btnCreatePage_OnClick", null);
             }
         }

         private string GetLayoutName(string contentTypeName)
         {
             string layoutURL = string.Empty;
             switch (contentTypeName)
             {
                 case "Article":
                     layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomArticle.aspx";
                     break;
                 case "Convention":
                     layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomConvention.aspx";
                     break;

                 default:
                     layoutURL = "/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx";
                     break;
             }

             return layoutURL;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hardik. But In my feature receiver, I am not able to use ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;  Is there something, I am missing? In a normal console app, I am able to create a page, based on my above code. But in a feature receiver , I am not able to do so.

Comment: Please use **Page.ClientScript**.. I have also updated my code so kindly try it.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get it working?

Comment: Hardik. My colleague has finished that part. He had the working code already. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. Did my code helped you anyhow? As it is doing the same as per your requirement.